# module not found in creating a menu

Tags: python-3.x

When running my program, it gives me the exception, 'modulenotfounderror'

the imported files are in the same folder and the names are exactly as they have been saved

```
import program5a
import program5

def main():
    print('Billing system menu')
    print('\t0 - End')
    print('\t1 - Enter Billing Data')
    print('\t2 - Display adhoc Billing Report')

    x = -1

    while x == -1:
        try:
            x = int(input('\nOption ==>'))

        except ValueError:
            x = -1

        x = int(input('\nOption ==>'))

        if x == 0:
            print('Program Ended')

        elif x == 1:
            program5.main()

        elif x == 2:
            program5a.main()

        else:
            x = -1

main()
```

Its expected to print the options and allow the user to enter a number 0,1,2 to run the other functions out of this convenient menu

Comment: Can you give us the full error message?

Comment: Also, after your `try`, `catch` block you immediately ask for an input again. That defeats the purpose of the that block.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/student/Desktop/Sophmore spring semester/Programming/programs/program 6.py", line 1, in <module>
    import program5a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'program5a'

Comment: there is the full error message sorry guys

Comment: @IFunball good call thank you, just trying to get my modules imported before i go over the smaller stuff

Comment: Okay, then something is wrong with your pathing. Try switching your `import` lines (i.e. make the `import program5` line come first) . Do you get the same error message as before? Or is it `program5` this time? These are two separate `py` files named `program5` and `program5a` in your execution directory, correct?

Comment: @IFunball yes there are two different programs and i just switched them so it seems to be a problem with the 5a one

Comment: I'm not quite sure then... maybe just try changing filename and your `import` statement to something like `program4` and see if that works. Something must be wrong with the naming if it is finding `program5` but not `program5a`.